# Replace string value in PowerBI using a wildcard

Tags: powerbi

I have a list of Points below that are in a column and i am trying to find all and replace them with just MaTmp.  I want to do like in excel with find and replace and use *MaTmp* and replace with MaTmp.  Any ideas?

| Points |
| --- |
| MaTmp01 |
| MaTmp02 |
| MaTmp1 |
| MaTmp-1 |
| MaTmp2 |
| MaTmp-2 |
| MaTmp3 |
| MaTmp-3 |

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using Power Query M Code:

*Paste the code into a blank query and examine the Applied Steps to better understand what's happening*

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8k0MyS0wMFSK1YGxjRBsJGFdJDaSCl0ktjGSMJAdCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Points = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Points", type text}}),
    MaTmp = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Points", each if Text.StartsWith(_,"MaTmp") then "MaTmp" else _})
in
    MaTmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are wildcards available but this line of code should achieve what you are trying to do

```
    ReplaceMaTmp = Table.TransformColumns(PrevStep,{{"Points", each if 
    Text.StartsWith(_,"MaTmp") then "MaTmp" else _}})
```